# How can I alter a MenuItem on the Options Menu on Android?

Tags: android, menuitem, options-menu, alternation

I have an Options Menu on my `Activity` with an `MenuItem` "Start". When this `MenuItem` is selected I would like to alter the Menu so it contains a `MenuItem` "Stop". And finally when "Stop" is selected, I would like to alter back to "Start".

Here is parts of my code that isn't working. I have both "Start" and "Stop" listed in `mymenu.xml` I should probably remove "stop" when the menu is created:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean isStarted = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        menu.removeItem(R.id.stop);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.start:
            isStarted = true;
            return true;
        case R.id.stop:
            isStarted = false;
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if(isStarted) {
            menu.removeItem(R.id.start);
            menu.add(R.id.stop);
        } else {
            menu.removeItem(R.id.stop);
            menu.add(R.id.start);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried to remove Stop when the menu is created? The code looks good. I can't spot anything which would cause issues other than that.

Comment: @Octavian: I tried with `menu.removeItem(R.id.stop);` after `getMenuInflater();` but it didn't work. I either get two menu items, one "start" and one "false" (should be "stop"), or the menu crashes when I should be shown.

Comment: where are you trying to call `removeItem()`? In `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`?

Comment: @Octavian: I remove the "stop" item in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` the first time, then I alter the items in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. I added this to the code in the question now.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

For this type of operation I usually choose not to alter the menu items, but just hide the ones you don't need:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.start).setVisible(!isStarted);
    menu.findItem(R.id.stop).setVisible(isStarted);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Just saw that I forgot to call the superclass as suggested earlier and specified in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) and the [source](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/app/Activity.java&d=3&l=2272)

Comment: And just to update, the source can be found at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/app/Activity.java?av=f#2272

Answer (score 21):

*Flygenring* answer is correct, but **menu.findItem()** is laggy and calling it within **onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)** produces bad user experience. It's better to get **MenuItem** object once while creating menu, and then just call setVisible each time menu occures on screen:

```
    MenuItem mDynamicMenuItem;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        // Get dynamic menu item
        mDynamicMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item);
        return true;
    }

    // Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is called right 
    // before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can use this method to
    // efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise dynamically modify the contents.
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        // Here is just a good place to update item
        mDynamicMenuItem.setVisible(isVisible);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: this method doesn't work when there are only one item in the menu.

Answer (score 6):

You probably need to call super.onPrepareOptionsMenu after you are finished making your changes.  From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)):

> Deriving classes should always call
>   through to the base class
>   implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution. You are basically deleting the `MenuItem` when calling `removeItem()` thus also deleting the reference. Using this code works.

```
private boolean isStarted = false;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 1:
        isStarted = true;
        return true;
    case 0:
        isStarted = false;
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if(isStarted) {
        menu.removeItem(1);
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Stop");
    } else {
        menu.removeItem(0);
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Start");
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

You have to create the `MenuItem` again. Thats also the reason for the `false` label. Actually you don't need the `MenuInflater` as you create the `Menu` via code so also no need for any menu XML file.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the info in this post as it solved my problem of the false labels in my menu.  I did have to modify it slightly and have the final code that works well as follows in the hope it saves someone else some time and frustration.  Its a slightly different solution but the main change I made was the .setVisible to either True or False, apart from that i.shadrins solution was the best fit for my needs.

```
    @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    if(loggedIn) 
    {
        logIn.setVisible(false);
        logOut.setVisible(true);
    } 
    else 
    {
        logIn.setVisible(true);
        logOut.setVisible(false);
    }
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    logIn = menu.findItem(R.id.loggedOut);
    logOut = menu.findItem(R.id.loggedIn);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: In which file it should be placed?

Answer (score 0):

On Android 3.0 and higher, you should call **invalidateOptionsMenu()** to request that the system calls **onPrepareOptionsMenu()**. You can then modify the options  menu in the method. You can check the **Changing menu items at runtime** section of the Android documentation here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#options-menu for more details.