# Android - Different menu items with TabLayout

Tags: android, menuitem, android-tablayout

I have in my app one `TabLayout`. I want every `fragment` has its own `menu items`. How I can do this? This is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setToolbar();
    setTabLayout();
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {

        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = null;

        switch(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
            case 1:

                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list, container, false);
                ...
                break;

            case 2:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
                ...
                break;
        }

        return rootView;
    }
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.list);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.map);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `invalidateOptionsMenu()` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. You should read documentation.

Take a close look at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu

Calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` on Android 3.0+ will call `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.  A `Menu` is passed to that method and you want to make the changes to menu using that object, whether it be adding or removing menu items.

Keep this in mind for `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`:

> You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false it will not be shown.

[Thanks to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908996/using-invalidateoptionsmenu-with-login-system-android/11942644#11942644)