# MenuItem setVisible(false) do not work in Android

Tags: android

I put my MenuItem in onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) and set visible false but there is no change.

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuItem mi = menu.findItem(R.id.example);
  mi.setVisible(false);
  return true;
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflater(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
  // ...
}
```

There are no exceptions or syntax errors.

Comment: The problem might be that you're not calling `super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);`  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199753/how-can-i-alter-a-menuitem-on-the-options-menu-on-android

Comment: @DanielNugent I just added "super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)" but it still does not work.

Comment: Are u trying to hide menuitem from fragment?

Comment: @LokeshDesai from Main Activity

Answer (score 1):

Control visibility of menu item in onCreateOptionsMenu methon, in onPrepareOptionsMenu only call invalidateOptionsMenu